# images don't show up when using url_for()

Tags: html, css, flask

I am using Tailwind inside my Flask project. And I want to insert a background image using `url_for()` inside style. I have the usual static folder recommanded by flask and inside it I have an images folder and inside it my background images folder as shown in the code bellow. The problem is that the image don't show up.

```
<div class="w-1/2" style="background-image: {{ url_for('static', filename='images/background/bg1.jpg') }}">
```

This is the tree of folders

```
-|App
----|static
----|templates
--------------|Authentication
----------------------------|index.html
```

I tried url_for() to insert the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the proper formatting of css's [`background-image`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.php) attribute. You need to put the link to the image into a special `url('')` format. In your case, you should be able to reference the image successfully with

```
<div class="w-1/2" style="background-image: url('{{ url_for('static', filename='images/background/bg1.jpg') }}')">
```

Comment: Thanks that was a perfect solution. you're right. I forget about the url.